# Error when accessing outlook emails that need SSO login, using javax mail

Tags: outlook, jakarta-mail, imap, pop3

I am trying to read outlook emails within my organization using javax mail, but I keep getting the error - "javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password."

One thing to note is that there is a Single Sign On required while logging into outlook. So you have to enter the same credentials (emailID/password) twice.

The following is my code -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String host = "pop.outlook.com";
    String mailStoreType = "pop3";
    String username = "firstname.lastname@companyName.com";
    String password = "password";
    check(host, mailStoreType, username, password);
}

public static void check(String host, String mailStoreType, String user, String password)
{
    try {
        //create properties field
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("mail.pop3.ssl.enable", "true");
        props.setProperty("mail.pop3.auth.plain.disable", "true");
        props.put("mail.pop3.host", host);
        props.put("mail.pop3.port", "995");
        props.setProperty("mail.pop3.starttls.enable", "true");
        Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);

        //create the POP3 store object and connect with the pop server
        Store store = emailSession.getStore(mailStoreType);
        store.connect(host, user, password);

        //create the folder object and open it
        Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
        emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

        // retrieve the messages from the folder in an array and print it
        Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();
        Logger.logConsoleMessage("messages.length---" + messages.length);

        for (int i = 0, n = messages.length; i < n; i++) {
            Message message = messages[i];
            Logger.logConsoleMessage("---------------------------------");
            Logger.logConsoleMessage("Email Number " + (i + 1));
            Logger.logConsoleMessage("Subject: " + message.getSubject());
            Logger.logConsoleMessage("From: " + message.getFrom()[0]);
            Logger.logConsoleMessage("Text: " + message.getContent().toString());
        }
        //close the store and folder objects
        emailFolder.close(false);
        store.close();

    } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

After tweaking the above code a little, i am able to access a gmail account, which leads me to believe that the error above is because of the extra authentication required by SSO. Has anyone encountered this ever ? Any inputs would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Probably the domain is configured not to allow plain authentication.  I don't know if there's anyway to apply MS's authentication to Pop3, or if they have a concept of application specific passwords you can generate.

Comment: Can you configure Thunderbird to access your outlook.com mailbox?  Also, the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) might provide more information about why it's failing.  You might need to set the [`mail.debug.auth`](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/package-summary.html#mail.debug.auth) property to true to get the full authentication exchange, but don't post that output here because it will contain your password.